# Remove white space and parenthsis from global from entry variable

Tags: templating, variable, string, globals

I am using a phone number in a global variable called `{{ global.phone }}` with the format "(555) 555-5555". I'd like to use that same variable/string and remove spaces, dash, and parenthesis to use for the href tel link. I've tried a few different things from Twig and Craft documentation, but nothing is working. Here's what I have right now.

```
<p>Ph: <a href="tel:{{ global.phone|trim(' ') }}">{{ global.phone }}</a><br/>
```

Is this possible to do? If so any advise how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried this but I think that you can use the twig [replace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) function. Something like:

```
{{ global.phone|replace({"(":"", ")":"", "-":"", " ":""}) }}
```

**Update** In your case, since the prefix (1-) is required, and "-" are allowable, the replace string for "(555) 555-5555" would be:

```
{{ global.phone|replace({"(" : "1-", ") " : "-"}) }}
```

Comment: Works great, however got an error with double pipe. Left one in code and it works no problem. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed that. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Which reminds me... I need to do that for a project I'm working on. So thanks! ;)

Comment: fyi... i think that the phone number needs to include the prefix (1-) and dashes are allowable (i.e. 1-555-555-5555). So you may need to prefix that number as well.

Comment: I'll use the latter, but looking at documentation and recommendations around web, not seeing a clear rule to use (1-) prefix or not. Same goes for including dashes or not. I've always done only numbers disregarding prefix and that's always worked for me.

Comment: Check out [this apple dev page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html). Looks like "+1" is the preferred prefix. The hyphens are completely optional.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, you can strip out all non-numerics with this something like this:

```
{{ globalPhoneNumber.phoneNumber|replace('/[^0-9]/', '') }}
```

Or, as part of a tel: anchor:

```
<a href="tel:{{ globalPhoneNumber.phoneNumber|replace('/[^0-9]/', '') }}">{{ globalPhoneNumber.phoneNumber }}</a>
```